# select all averages of all fields from a view without specifying field names

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, mariadb

So I have fairly wide views in my database. I have the following dummy view that's generated from several tables. `SELECT * FROM view_name;` yields the following:

```
field1      field2      field3      field4      field5
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           4           7           10          15
2           5           8           11          14
3           6           9           12          13
```

To get their averages I have to name each and every field I want the average from:

`SELECT avg(field1), avg(field2), avg(field3), avg(field4), avg(field5) FROM view_name;`

which yields the result:

```
avg(field1)  avg(field2)  avg(field3)  avg(field4)  avg(field5)
-----------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
2.0          5.0          8.0          11.0         14.0
```

Some of the actual use cases have views that are 20-25 fields wide due to their report-like purpose, and it would make writing queries much easier if I didn't have to specify each and every column from which I would like to get average from, and I'm wondering if there's any workarounds around this? **The databases I'm using are sqlite and mariadb, so any solution that works for either of them would be acceptable.**

In short, I'm kind of looking for a way to specify that I want to get all averages of all fields without specifying field names, just like `SELECT *` works and return them just like the above query. An analogue that violates the syntax would be

`SELECT * FROM view_name` and `SELECT AVG(*) FROM view_name`

If you would like to use the dummy view I created, you can use a dummy table to simulate it (the actual views, as mentioned, are much wider than this table):

```
CREATE table dummy (
field1 int,
field2 int,
field3 int,
field4 int,
field5 int
);

INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (1,4,7,10,15);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (2,5,8,11,14);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (3,6,9,12,13);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('AVG(',column_name,')')),' FROM view_name') 
FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'view_name' INTO @query;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;

+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| AVG(field1) | AVG(field2) | AVG(field3) | AVG(field4) | AVG(field5) |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      2.0000 |      5.0000 |      8.0000 |     11.0000 |     14.0000 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Further, it can be wrapped into a stored routine to make the view name a parameter. The idea is that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` contains all column names for a table/view, and they can be searched and filtered using various criteria.